# Insert a $key as an variable in a foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I have this array:

```
$lista_agregados = array('po' => '0', 'brita' => '0');
```

And these arrays:

```
$po = array(0 => array('qt' => 12, 'total' => 1234),  
            1 => array('qt' => 45, 'total' => 13224));
$brita = array(0 => array('qt' => 54, 'total' => 124),  
            1 => array('qt' => 18, 'total' => 224));
```

I want to use a loop instead of explicit operations for every key in `$lista_agregados`:

```
$somatorio_mensal['po'] = $po[0]['total'] + $po[1]['total'];
$somatorio_mensal['brita'] = $brita[0]['total'] + $brita[1]['total'];
```

This is what I have so far:

```
foreach ($lista_agregados as $key => $value) {
    $somatorio_mensal["'$key'"] = $key[0]['total'] + $key[1]['total'];
}
```

The problem is that `$key[0]` is interpreted as `po[0]` instead of `$po[0]`. 
Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Few things: 1) `"'$key'"` assuming `$key = "test";` your key will be `'test'` and you would have to access it with: `$arr["'test'"]`, note the single quotes! Now you probably want to use just `$key`, so you access the element with `$arr["test"]` 2) For your "problem" you want to look at variable variables in the manual, e.g. `$$key`, so you basically say take the value of `$key` as variable name and if `$key = "po";` do `$po`. 3) And last look at `array_column()` and `array_sum()` to add up all total elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($lista_agregados as $key => $value) {
    $somatorio_mensal[$key] = ${$key}[0]['total'] + ${$key}[1]['total'];
}
```

Comment: Ok, maybe give a hint to: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect

Answer (score 3):

Use a feature called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
foreach ($lista_agregados as $sub => $unused) {
  // refer to variable called "$" + "$sub"
  if (!isset(${$sub}))
    continue;
  $a = ${$sub}; 

  if (! is_array($a))
    continue;

  $somatorio_mensal[$sub] = 0;
  foreach ($a as $k => $v)
    $somatorio_mensal[$sub] += $v['total'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Be warned that you have `brita1` as one of your keys, but the variable is called `brita`. With that fixed, you can do it like this:

```
foreach($lista_agregados as $key => $total) {
    foreach($$key as $k) {
        $lista_agregados[$key] += $k['total'];
    }
}
```